# PHP + CURL - commonsMultipartFile error?

Tags: php, curl

I've received tech support from the folks behind the API I'm trying to utilize, but they aren't well-versed in PHP and have been less than helpful. I thought perhaps I could get some help here.

I'm trying to make a CURL request via PHP. The tech guy says he is using the following CURL command via CLI and it's working just fine:

```
curl -X POST -k -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW" -F "hash=a0fbb9f14e6965300d6736f65cd98e82" -F "timestamp=1424088034782" -F "username=David" -F "placementType=SITE_PLACEMENT" -F "campaignId=333" -F "active=true" -F "name=complex" -F "weight=1" -F "adUnitId=1" -F "bannerType=LOCAL_FILE" -F "imageFile=@c:/scripts/1.gif" -F "url=http://qwe.com" -F "imageBannerLink=http://qwe.com" "https://theapi.com/create.do"
```

Most of those fields aren't important. Via PHP, I can make a similar request, but instead of sending an imageFile, I simply send a URL the image lives at and the service uses the externally hosted image. By adding the `imageFile` parameter, the service should instead create a local copy of the image and save it there, which is the goal. So that's the only field that is varying between a working example and a non-working one.

So here's my current PHP code that isn't working:

```
                $local_file_absolute = realpath($local_file);
                $cfile = new CURLFile($local_file_absolute); //cfile is valid, I've checked
                $creative_fields = array();
                //...add all the fields that are fine because they work for the external hosting strategy, match those in the given CLI CURL request...//
                $creative_fields['imageFile'] = $cfile;
                    $ch = curl_init('https://theapi.com/create.do);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $creative_fields);
                    $verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
                    $response = curl_exec($ch);
                    rewind($verbose);
                    $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);

                    echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
```

My verbose log gives me a 400 error from the receiving server that says `HTTP Status 400 - {commonsMultipartFile=must be image or flash file}`. This fails for .jpgs, .pngs and .gifs (.gif being what the tech guy is using). I've also tried using both the PHP `CURLFile` class and the path with `@` at the beginning - both get the same error.

Like I said, by omitting the `imageFile` field and using the externally hosted strategy, the request works just fine, and the CLI version from the tech guy also supposedly works. I've tried on both my localhost and a live server, so I assume the issue is with how I'm sending the file.

Any thoughts? Let me know if I should add more details.

**UPDATE**
I wrote my own script to receive my request and it gets the file just fine, which leads me to believe it's an issue on the vendor's end. Will continue to update.

**UPDATE 2**
I didn't realize that the CURLFile class won't try to guess at a MIME type - you have to explicitly pass it. That was the issue. Taken care of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that the CURLFile class won't try to guess at a MIME type - you have to explicitly pass it. That was the issue. Taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

I use this for all my CURL ops and havn't had any problems (apart from tweaking formatting on result):

```
    $ch = curl_init("url here");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    echo '<!-- '. $result. ' -->'; // THIS LINE IS FOR DEBUG PURPOSES ONLY-IT WILL SHOW IN HTML COMMENTS
    $data=strstr($result,'<');
    $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $data, $vals, $index);
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
    $params = array();
    $level = array();
    foreach ($vals as $xml_elem) {
     if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'open') {
        if (array_key_exists('attributes',$xml_elem)) {
             list($level[$xml_elem['level']],$extra) = array_values($xml_elem['attributes']);
        } else {
             $level[$xml_elem['level']] = $xml_elem['tag'];
        }
     }
     if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'complete') {
        $start_level = 1;
        $php_stmt = '$params';
        while($start_level < $xml_elem['level']) {
             $php_stmt .= '[$level['.$start_level.']]';
             $start_level++;
        }
       $php_stmt .= '[$xml_elem[\'tag\']] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
       if(isset($xml_elem['value']))
       eval($php_stmt);
     }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $params;
```

EDIT:

obviously put your xml query or w/e in $data